# Trying to do cross correlation in C

Tags: c, matlab, cross-correlation

I am doing a project which is locating a sound source. I am using three microphones to capture data and then do cross correlation to find the time difference. The time difference is then used to locate the sound source. The issue I think am having is with the cross correlation of my code. I am doing this in C and from my understanding FFT needs to be done and so I am using the FFTW library to do this. The result of my cross correlation is always 0. The microphones are capturing data by sampling them, and then after a loud sound it captures data for half a buffer and then writes the data to a text file. I am using a circular buffer for storing the data. After the trigger event occurs, the data is reordered and then fast fourier transformed. Then multiplied and then inverse transformed. I then determine when the peak occurs from the output of the IFFT. Most of the time it is 0 but I am not sure why. So I wrote the data into a text file where I then imported the data into MATLAB. This was to test the xcorr function with my data. The results of this match my cross correlation code in C. So I am now not sure of where the issue lies with my code.

I have added a link to the data I acquired in a text file.[1](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GMjCDFDrjKQNfL2UBcCktM8D5O2Nq-_V?usp=sharing) Then for my cross correlation in C I have the following code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>    /* Standard Library of Complex Numbers */
#include <fftw3.h>

int i,size = 8;                                         //defining the size of the buffer and FFT

int peak_detec(double);
void reverse(double a[]);

int peak_detec(double a)        // function which calculates the maximum value of an array
{
    int b= 0;
    double Largest; 
    int Position;
    Largest = a;
    for(b=1; b<10; b++)
    {
        if(Largest<a)
        {
            Largest=a;
            Position = b;
        }   
    }
    return Position;

}

void reverse(double a[])                    // function which reverses the order of the array send to the function
{
    int i; 
    double temp[size];
    for(i = 1; i < size+1; i++)
    {
        temp[i-1] = a[size-i];
    }
    for (i=0; i< size;i++)
    {
    a[i]=temp[i];
    }
}
int main(void)
{
double array[] = {0.7,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1};     //my two arrays for FFT
double array2[] = {0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.7,0.1};    

double *out,*out2,*out3;                                //pointer for the output 
double *err,*err2;                                      //pointer for errors
double *double_array;
double *double_array2;

//****pointer for complex arrays****//
double complex *out_cpx;                                
double complex *out_cpx2;                               
double complex *out_cpx3;                               

//****defining all the plans for fft****//
fftw_plan fft;
fftw_plan ifft;
fftw_plan fft2;
fftw_plan ifft2;
fftw_plan ifft3;
//****allocating memory****//
out_cpx = (double complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double complex)*(2*size));
out = (double *) malloc((2*size)*sizeof(double));
err = (double *) malloc((2*size)*sizeof(double));
out_cpx2 = (double complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double complex)*(2*size));
out2 = (double *) malloc((2*size)*sizeof(double));
err2 = (double *) malloc((2*size)*sizeof(double));
out_cpx3 = (double complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double complex)*(2*size));
out3 = (double *) malloc((2*size)*sizeof(double));

double_array = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(2*size));
double_array2 = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(2*size));

//****setting up fftw and ifft plans****//
fft = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d((2*size), double_array, out_cpx, FFTW_ESTIMATE);  //Setup fftw plan for fft
ifft = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d((2*size), out_cpx, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);   //Setup fftw plan for ifft
fft2 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d((2*size), double_array2, out_cpx2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);  //Setup fftw plan for fft
ifft2 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d((2*size), out_cpx2, out2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);   //Setup fftw plan for ifft
ifft3 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d((2*size), out_cpx3, out3, FFTW_ESTIMATE);   //Setup fftw plan for ifft


//reverse(array2);

memcpy (double_array, array, sizeof(double)*(size));
memset (double_array + size+1, 0, sizeof(double) * (size-1));

memcpy (double_array2, array2, sizeof(double)*(size));
memset (double_array2 + size+1, 0, sizeof(double) * (size-1));

//****executing fft****//
fftw_execute(fft);
fftw_execute(fft2);

double complex scale = 1.0/(2 * size);
for (i=0;i<2*size;i++)  //loop which multiplies the FFT arrays
{
    out_cpx3[i] = out_cpx[i]*out_cpx2[i]*scale;

}

//****executing ifft****//
fftw_execute(ifft);
fftw_execute(ifft2);
fftw_execute(ifft3);

//****for loop which finds the largest value of the array****//
int Position =0;
double Largest;

Largest = out3[0];
for(i=1; i<2*size; i++)
{   
    if(Largest<=out3[i])
    {
        Largest=out3[i];
        Position = i ;
    }   
}
printf("Position of peak value: %d\n",Position);


//****frees the memory****//
fftw_destroy_plan(fft);
fftw_destroy_plan(fft2);
fftw_destroy_plan(ifft);
fftw_destroy_plan(ifft2);
fftw_destroy_plan(ifft3);
fftw_free(out_cpx);
fftw_free(out_cpx2);
fftw_free(out_cpx3);
free(double_array);
free(double_array2);
free(err);
free(out);
free(err2);
free(out2);
free(out3);

return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help with my issue? I am trying to do cross correlation and with the data in the shared link but does not seem to work.
It is my first time asking a question on here, I think I have given enough information but if not then I can try provide more if something does not make sense.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: The `memcpy` and `memset` calls leave an element uninitialized. The `memcpy` call copies `FFT_size` elements, filling in elements from index 0 to index `FFT_size-1`. Then the `memset` call uses `double_array + FFT_size+1`, which starts at the element with index `FFT_size+1`. That leaves the element with index `FFT_size` uninitialized.

Comment: “The result of my cross correlation is always 0” is an inadequate description of the problem. Your program has several outputs: “Position of highest value…”, “delay of 1 and 2…”, “Time difference…”, et cetera. Which of those is zero? Or is the entire arrays resulting from the inverse FFTs that are zero?

Comment: Code for `peak_detec2` is not shown. Include everything in your [mre]. Start with an FFT size of four, or maybe even one or two, and some hard-coded sample data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Okay I will  work on shortening the code. About the always 0, I mean the peak of where the cross correlation peak occurs is at 0. So after the IFFT, I determine the peak and the position of where this peak value occurs is at 0. I have tried this method with smaller and simpler arrays to test if it works and it has. So using an array of 8, I did FFT then multiplication and then IFFT. The outcome of this was fine, I was getting correct results but when I use the data I sample and store from the microphones it does not give desired outputs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have made changes to the code. Hopefully this is easier

Comment: a tip for future. Replace `out = (double *) malloc((2*size)*sizeof(double));` with `out = malloc(2 * size * sizeof *out);`. It's both shorted and more robust

Comment: @tstanisl why are the double parts not needed?

Comment: @Danyalqasim, malloc() returns 'void*' what can be converted to any pointer type without cast. Thus cast is redundant. Avoiding 'double' in malloc() will let auto-adjusting the size whenever type of variable 'out' is changed.

Comment: @tstanisl, okay thank you. Will make those changes